# Using laravel in a subdirectory, without root access

Tags: php, apache, laravel

A year ago, I decided to go with codeigniter instead of laravel, because codeigniter prooved to be easier to setup. I am now preparing for my next project and it seems as if codeigniter is now obsolete (at least most of the people seem to recommend laravel over codeigniter).

Now to my problem: I use a virtual ubuntu machine for developing web apps so I have a dev environment similar to the production environment (this helps me to avoid some problems (especially case-sensitivity...;)))

I installed composer and laravel and created a new laravel project named "quickstart" in /var/www/quickstart. I then followed their "getting started guide" (here: [Guide](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart)). So far everything worked.

But here come the problems: 
I have two other web applications in /var/www, so when I enter the ip of the machine I see the 3 directories.

Issue 1:
Normaly I'd expect that as soon as if I click on the "quickstart"-Directory in my browser, the webapp would get displayed, but I have to click a second time on "public", and then the webapp is displayed.

Issue 2: Of course, the links on the page are wrong too, because they reeer to (for example) "/task", which can't be found on the server.

The problem is that I'm not really experienced with apache configuration. I suspect it has something to do with VirtualHosts, but AFAIK you need to have root access to configure virtual hosts, and I do not have root rights on the dev environment.

Could you point out a way to me how I can make laravel work in a subdirectory in a way that I can just move the files and folders to my hoster as soon as I have finished the project? I'd like to then change only one file, and not all paths and URLs in all files ;)

Regards,
Christian

Comment: How come are you not using [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead)? It's exactly what you're trying to do, but already prepackaged and very easy to configure for multiple apps.

Comment: Hey Bogdan. I know about Homestead. The "problem" is that it just works: I fear that I develop the webapp and find out afterwards that I can't get it to work with my hoster. Thats why I need to find out upfront if I can get it to work;)

Comment: What type of hosting are you using: shared, vps or dedicated?

Comment: It's a shared hosting

Comment: In that case you should read [this article](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e), because Laravel was not made to work on shared hosting out of the box, which means you will need to make some changes for it to work.

Comment: Hi Bogdan. Thank you for the link! I'll try it out as soon as I can and then report back. :)

Comment: Hi Bogdan. Many thanks for your reply, which really pointed me in the right direction! (Maybe you want to add it as answer, so I can mark it as correct?). However, I think I'll decide against Laravel, because I don't want having to change the app everytime I publish it, it's just too error prone. (I just want to delete the whole directory and push the updated app ;))

Comment: Just because you have to make some changes for it to work on the server, doesn't mean you need to make them every time. You could set it up in your virtual machine the same way as you would on your shared server, which would mean just copying the files when deploying to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bogdan, I was able to figure it out. My hoster allows symlinks, so I did it like so:

I put the laravel installation in

```
/srv/web/quickstart
```

(quickstart is the name of the project). I then created the following symlink:

```
ln -s /srv/web/quickstart/public /srv/web/www/public
```

The document root of the apache is configured to

```
/srv/web/www/public
```

After that I just got a blank page. That was because I forgot to set the correct permissions on the storage-folder. So I set the following permissions

```
chmod -R 777 /srv/web/quickstart/storage
```

This is fine for a development environment. For production I'd recommend to only allow the webserver-user to write into that directory.

And voilà: Everything works!

Thank you for your help bogdan.
Christian